# Dumping the GOT with gdb at run time

Tags: binary-analysis, gdb, elf, plt, got

I want to see how the plt stubs are being resolved at run time when lazy linking is used and how the GOT is changed along the way. How can I dump the GOT with gdb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of options for this.

- Use [pwndbg](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg) or [gef](https://github.com/hugsy/gef). They have a command called `got` which looks like this

```
gef➤  got

GOT protection: Partial RelRO | GOT functions: 4

[0x555555755018] free@GLIBC_2.2.5  →  0x555555554606
[0x555555755020] puts@GLIBC_2.2.5  →  0x555555554616
[0x555555755028] malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5  →  0x555555554626
[0x555555755030] sprintf@GLIBC_2.2.5  →  0x555555554636
```

```
pwndbg> got

GOT protection: Partial RELRO | GOT functions: 4

[0x555555755018] free@GLIBC_2.2.5 -> 0x555555554606 (free@plt+6) ◂— push   0 /* 'h' */
[0x555555755020] puts@GLIBC_2.2.5 -> 0x555555554616 (puts@plt+6) ◂— push   1
[0x555555755028] malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 -> 0x555555554626 (malloc@plt+6) ◂— push   2
[0x555555755030] sprintf@GLIBC_2.2.5 -> 0x555555554636 (sprintf@plt+6) ◂— push   3
```

- According to [their](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg/blob/cc0c90a4a4599ca6f0470157db5fc78c2708a904/pwndbg/wrappers/readelf.py#L15) [sources](https://github.com/hugsy/gef/blob/7bd407a1bb90e34730351715d323bc905275859a/gef.py#L8745) both use `readelf` as such to display this information

```
$ readelf --relocs ll
Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x4a0 contains 9 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000200dd8  000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                    750
000000200de0  000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                    710
000000201040  000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                    201040
000000200fd0  000200000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 _ITM_deregisterTMClone + 0
000000200fd8  000400000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
000000200fe0  000500000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000200fe8  000700000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 _Jv_RegisterClasses + 0
000000200ff0  000900000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 _ITM_registerTMCloneTa + 0
000000200ff8  000a00000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0

Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x578 contains 4 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000201018  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 free@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
000000201020  000300000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 puts@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
000000201028  000600000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
000000201030  000800000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 sprintf@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
```

And then use this output to dump GOT while debugging.

- Another method is to use `plt` symbols to resolve `got`

```
pwndbg> disass 'puts@plt'
Dump of assembler code for function puts@plt:
   0x0000555555554610 <+0>: jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200a0a]        # 0x555555755020
   0x0000555555554616 <+6>: push   0x1
   0x000055555555461b <+11>:    jmp    0x5555555545f0
End of assembler dump.
pwndbg> tele 0x555555755020
00:0000│   0x555555755020 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+32) —▸ 0x7ffff7aa2f90 (puts) ◂— push   r13
01:0008│   0x555555755028 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+40) —▸ 0x7ffff7ab4f10 (malloc) ◂— push   rbp
02:0010│   0x555555755030 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+48) —▸ 0x7ffff7a892d0 (sprintf) ◂— sub    rsp, 0xd8
03:0018│   0x555555755038 (data_start) ◂— 0x0
04:0020│   0x555555755040 (__dso_handle) ◂— 0x555555755040 /* '@PuUUU' */
05:0028│   0x555555755048 (completed) ◂— 0x0
... ↓
pwndbg> print puts
$13 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7aa2f90 <_IO_puts>
```